# Matlab simulation of dog chasing a rabbit pursuit curve.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

Hi I'm really struggling with this problem of mine.

A rabbit is running along the x-axis ($0\to \infty$) with a constant velocity $v_r$ and a dog chases the rabbit starting at some point $L (0\cdots \infty)$ on the y-axis with a constant velocity $v_d$. The velocity vector of the dog is always pointing towards the rabbits location.

So I need the differential equation for the location of the dog and solve it numerically using matlab. To be exact, I need to plot the pursuit curve of the dog.

I also need to determine the time it takes to catch the rabbit (distance < 0.1m) at varying values of vr, vd and L (with matlab).

I can't make any sense of the examples I found over the past few days and can't figure out the use of ode45 function either.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by formulating your system.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx_r}{dt} &= v_r, \\
\frac{dy_r}{dt} &= 0, \\
\frac{dx_d}{dt} &= v_{dx}, \\
\frac{dy_d}{dt} &= v_{dy}.
\end{align*}$$

Now, $v_{dx}$ and $v_{dy}$ are determined by the vector from the rabbit to the dog. In other words, they proportional to $v_d$ as the component of the vector $(x_r-x_d, y_r-y_d)$ are proportional to its overall magnitude. In other words, you should get

$$v_{dx} = v_d \cdot \frac{x_r-x_d}{\sqrt{(x_r-x_d)^2+(y_r-y_d)^2}}$$

and similarly for $v_{dy}$.

Now you have a first-order nonlinear system. You should be able to set up initial conditions, and `ode45` should suit you just fine.

To use it, let's set up our function handle

```
%X = [x_r; y_r; x_d; y_d]
f = @(t,X)[v_r*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01);...
           0;...
           v_d*(X(1)-X(3))./norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01);...
           v_d*(X(2)-X(4))./norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01)];
```

Note that `norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])` just gives you the magnitude of the vector between the animals (e.g. the absolute distance).

The weird line that I put in the function handle ad the end of each line, `*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01)]` sets the system to be identically zero if our terminal condition is met. This is a hack! If the dog gets too close, we begin dividing by a small number and things go chaotic.

Normally, we might try a shooting method, but our initial conditions are well-specified.

Now just call `ode45`:

```
[tout, xout] = ode45(f,[0 T],x0);
```

To compute the distance between the animals, it is simple:

```
delta = sqrt((xout(:,1)-xout(:,3)).^2+(xout(:,2)-xout(:,4)).^2);
```

Comment: If this is homework, please feel free to ask me specific questions about the code. If you still struggle, I will provide full code after your assignment is due.

Comment: Okay I think I now understand the math of this problem. Thanks for the clear explanation.
But, I'm still having problems with matlab.

Comment: Google Matlab function handles for a start.

Comment: Matlab says "Not enough input arguments." when trying to use the function handle. What is the cause for this?

Comment: Define your initial conditions as `x0 = [R,0,0,D]` where R is the starting position of the rabbit on the x axis, and D is the fogs position on y.

Comment: Am I supposed to use the commented X = [x_r; y_r; x_d; y_d] for something or is it just to clarify the code?

Comment: It is just to clarify the order of the arguments 8n the vector X.

Comment: So now the code looks like thisclear all;

v_r = 1;
v_d = 1;

R = 0;
D = 10;

x0 = [R;0;0;D];
t = 0:0.01:10;
T = 10;

f = @(t,X)[v_r*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01);...
           0;...
           v_d*(X(1)-X(3))./norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01);...
           v_d*(X(2)-X(4))./norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])*(norm([X(1)-X(3); X(2)-X(4)])>.01)];
       
[tout, xout] = ode45(t,f,[0 T],x0);

Comment: Oops not so neat..

Comment: `ode45` is an adaptive step-size method, you only need to specify the endpoints of your time interval, so just specify the stop time `T = 10`. Get rid of the line `t=0:.01:10` entirely, it's not needed. I believe I have set up my code so that we want `xout` to be a n-by-4 matrix, each column pertaining to a single state's history. So `x0 = [R, 0, 0, D]`. I had mistakenly added semicolons before.

Comment: If you get an error, just try putting the semi-colons back in -- I'm not currently at the computer I put the code together on.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now! The ode45 call had t as the first argument which I think was not supposed to be there so I removed it and now I'm getting some response from the code. Thank you so much for your time and help! :)

Comment: Antero -- so it did! That's my fault, I copied and pasted in haste. Sorry!!